# Como configurar o Log4j para gerar um arquivo na pasta WEB-INF com data diferentes?

Tags: java-ee, apache, vraptor, log4j

Quero gerar arquivos *.log ou *.txt com datas diferentes (ex: file-log-22-10-2015.log) dentro da pasta WEB-INF do meu projeto JavaWeb crei o arquivo log4j.proprieties da seguinte forma:

log4j.properties

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, stdout, file

# Redirect log messages to console
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

# Redirect log messages to a log file, support file rolling.
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=/WEB-INF/logs
log4j.appender.file.DatePattern='.'dd-MM-yyyy
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=5MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

Porém ele não gera e da o seguinte erro no console:

> log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger
>   (br.com.meusistema.ClasseTeste). log4j:WARN Please initialize the
>   log4j system properly. log4j:WARN See
>   http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.

O arquivo properties está na pasta WEB-INF e estou chamando o logger dentro da classe normal conforme abaixo.

ClasseTeste.java:

```
package br.com.meusistema;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class ClasseTeste{
    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(ClasseTeste.class);

    public void metodoTeste(){
        BasicConfigurator.configure();
        log.info("iniciando Teste");
    }
}
```

A estrutura esta assim usando o log4j1

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E mesmo depois de tudo isso não gera o arquivo. Retirei esse método da documentação, e estou usando o Vraptor.

Comment: Se estiver usando o log4j1 ele precisa estar dentro    , se estiver usando o log4j2 o arquivo precisa estar no SRC do seu projeto, e esta faltando `log4j.appender.file.Append=true` não me recordo se ele reconhece o caminho relativo de onde você quer gravar acredito que seria algo como `log4j.appender.file.File=seucaminho inteiro para o  web inf /WEB-INF/logs`

Comment: @WellingtonAvelino ta conforme a estrutura acima

Comment: Muda o `File= ` coloca o caminho certinho, não achei na documentação falando que ele consegue fazer como você colocou, eu sempre falo o caminho que eu quero. @TiagoFerezin

Comment: ok tentei outra forma e deu certo em breve dps dos testes irei postar a solução que encontrei @WellingtonAvelino

Comment: Como você passou o caminho?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para configurar o log4j.properties em projeto Java Web primeiro deve-se colocar o log4j-1.2.17.jar na pasta
WEB-INF>lib, deve-se certificar que a livraria Web App Library [FeltexLog4J] está nas dependências e deve ser retirada as dependências do log4j do Maven, e não pode existir o arquivo log4j.xml no projeto, pois esse anula as configurações do properties, pela linha de prioridade.

Web App Libraries[FeltexLog4J]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O arquivo log4j.properties deve ser criado na pasta /src do projeto dentro do Java Resources conforme representado abaixo:

[image: Estrutura do projeto]

As configurações deverá ser feita desse modo, conforme exemplo do log4j.properties abaixo:

Baixo Nível (Mais detalhes) =================================== Alto Nível (Menos detalhe)
ALL => TRACE => DEBUG => INFO => WARN => ERROR => FATAL

## log4j.properties

```
# Níveis: ALL, DEBUG, ERROR, FATAL, INFO, OFF,TRACE, WAR

#Nível de Log INFO Saídas A1 e Console
log4j.rootLogger= ALL, A1, Console

#Informando qual o tipo de geração do arquivo de log. Neste caso será diário
log4j.appender.A1=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender

#Onde será gravado o arquivo de Log e qual será o seu nome
log4j.appender.A1.file=caminho do arquivo a ser gerado com o nome.

#Definição de um padrão de saída de log para A1
log4j.appender.A1.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout

#Padrão de data como 2050-01-31 (AnoAnoAnoAno-MesMes-Dia-Dia)
log4j.appender.A1.DatePattern='_'dd-MM-yyyy'.log'

#Definição de como será exibida cada lilha de LOG
log4j.appender.A1.layout.ConversionPattern=%p - %d{dd/MM/yyyy - HH:mm:ss} - ProjetoNome - %m %n

#Define o tamanho máximo do arquivo log
log4j.appender.A1.MaxFileSize=5MB

#Define quantos backup terá no máximo
log4j.appender.A1.MaxBackupIndex=100000

#Uma nova saída para o LOG, neste caso a console para IDE (Eclipse o NetBeans) ou prompt (Windows ou Linux)
log4j.appender.Console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender

#Definição de um padrão de saída de log para Console
log4j.appender.Console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout

#Uma nova saída para o LOG, neste caso a console para IDE (Eclipse o NetBeans) ou prompt (Windows ou Linux)
log4j.appender.Console.layout.ConversionPattern=%p - %d{dd/MM/yyyy - HH:mm:ss} - ProjetoNome - %m %n
```

Tem um projeto semi feito e funcionando e ta estruturado da forma que consegui fazer, nesse link.
[FeltexLog4J +  log4j-1.2.17.jar](http://www.feltex.com.br/dados/projetos/FeltexLog4J.war)